# Using mysql workbench reverse enginerring command line

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a live database and i was trying to generate model/ E-R diagram for database visualization.

Opened command line help but can't really find the way to do the same.

I don't have a UI support where my sql database exist.

Can i generate the E-R diagram or model from it using command line options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the EER diagrams from MySQL Workbench main screen. You don't have to have a GUI in your server since you can connect to it from the PC running Workbench. All you have to do is set up a connection to your server in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: was trying that and it gives me this error, `Operation failed: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111` so using erviz for now, but mysql workbench looks better to me.

Comment: try to connect to the database using a SSH connection "Standard TCP/IP over SSH"

Answer (score 1):

you cannot, but following commands should give you an idea what's inside:

- show databases;
- use *databaseName*; show tables;
- show create table *tableName*;